# Why are there connections between these points in chartjs?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, ng2-charts

I have an angular apllication I which I display a chart. The chart is filled with data from a database. The y axis displays sensordata and the x axis displays a timestamp. The timestamp is also a column in the database. When I start the app there are connections between some points that I don´t want and that don´t make sense! Why is that so?
[image]

```
ngOnInit(): void {
var chartOptions = {
            plugins: {
                legend: {
                    display: false
                }
            },
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            animation: {duration: 0}
        };

 var tempChart = new Chart('tempChart', {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: [],
            datasets: [{
                data: [0],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: chartOptions
    }); 

setInterval(() => { 
        // API request
        this.service.getMesswerte().subscribe({
          next: data => {
                this.chartData = data;
                this.fillChartData(this.chartData);
          }
        })
       }, 1000)

 setInterval(() => { 
        tempChart.data.datasets[0].data = this.tempArray;
        tempChart.update();
       }, 1000)
}
private fillChartData(chartData: Object) 
{
    this.objects = Object.values(chartData);
    for(let row in this.objects)
    {
        this.tempObject = {
            x: this.objects[row].timestamp,
            y: this.objects[row].airtemp
        }

      this.tempArray.push(this.tempObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid any answer at the moment will just be a guess as we cannot tell from an image what the underlying cause may be. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and put a runnable snippet into your question which shows the problem.

Comment: I updated my question now. I hope you can help me now!

Comment: Can yo make a runnable snippet as shown in the link I gave?